# Converting subimage to RGB-A

Tags: java, sprite, transparency, bufferedimage

I am working on a 2D platform game and I have a sprite sheet which includes the sprites of tiles and blocks.

I noticed that there was a pink-ish background behind the transparent sprites so I thought that Java wasn't loading the sprites as PNG and I tried to re-draw the sprite on a new bufferedImage, pixel by pixel checking if the pixel was *R=255*, *G=63*, *B=52* but unfortunately, the code wasn't able to detect that either and at this point I have no more options left to try.

I made sure that the "pink" color values are correct by using a color picker.
[image] 
[image]

original spritesheet (transparent):
[image]

The class that loads the sprite(s) is:

```
public class SpriteSheet {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


    public BufferedImage grabImage(int col, int row, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage alpha = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        BufferedImage img = image.getSubimage(
                (col * width) - width, 
                (row * height) - height, 
                width, 
                height);


        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                int pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);
                int red, green, blue;

                red         = (pixel >> 16)     & 0xff;
                green   = (pixel >> 8)  & 0xff;
                blue    = (pixel)       & 0xff;

                if(red == 255 && green == 63 && blue == 52)
                    alpha.setRGB(x, y, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).getRGB());         
                else
                    alpha.setRGB(x, y, pixel);  


            }   
        }

        return alpha;
    }


}
```

the class that loads the sprite sheet is:

```
public class Texture {

    SpriteSheet bs, ss;
    private BufferedImage block_sheet = null;
    public BufferedImage[] block = new BufferedImage[3];


    public Texture() {

        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        try {
            block_sheet = loader.loadImage("/tiles.png");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        bs = new SpriteSheet(block_sheet);

        getTextures();

    }


    private void getTextures() {
        block[0] = bs.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32);
        block[1] = bs.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
        block[2] = bs.grabImage(4, 1, 32, 32);
    }

}
```

How do I get rid of the pink-ish background and keep transparency?

Comment: i think what is happening, you are loading image as format which does not support alpha channel. issue will be in place where you are initially load your image. so could you post code to your imageloader

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you're using `subImage`.

```
try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/image.png"));
            for (int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) {

                    Color pixelcolor = new Color(img.getRGB(i, j));
                    int r = pixelcolor.getRed();
                    int g = pixelcolor.getGreen();
                    int b = pixelcolor.getBlue();

                    if (r == 255 && g == 63 && b == 52) {
                        int rgb = new Color(255, 255, 255).getRGB();
                        img.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
                    }
                }
            }

            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("D:/transparent.png"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: The reason i used subimage was because I wanted to get that part of the spritesheet, as you would do in a css file.
  `getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h)
Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region.`

Comment: I tried this code to your image without it and it worked

Comment: is your code, creating a new image file ? if so, that is not what im looking for. I want to load it directly from the sprite sheet. possibly push it trough some sort of process in order to save the transparency.

Comment: yes I just created new image to check if the code works or not

Answer (score 0):

***cough***, It worked all along, I had forgotten to disable the test blocks which was representing the blocks. Realized this after some time.

So the transparency was working fine. I just saw the rectangle i was drawing behind it.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution! However, I suggest you just delete the entire question, as it doesn't really help others with the same problem (the buggy code isn't even in the question).